# ¿Cómo pasar valores en ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

**Página 1**.

`Textbox` cuyo valor se enviará a la **Página 2**:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbNombre" Width="200px">
```

Evento que enviará el valor:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDatos" Width="100px" Height="75px" onclick="btnDatos_Click">
```

Método `click` del botón:

```
protected void btnDatos_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?nombre=" + txbNombre.Text);
}
```

**Página 2**:

`Label` que recibira el valor:

```
   <asp:Label ID="lbUsuario" runat="server" Text="Label">
```

`Load` de la **Página 2**.

Cuando cargue la segunda página automáticamente debe aparecer como valor del `label` el valor del `Textbox` de la **página 1**:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    lbUsuario.Text = ....;     
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma en que envías el parámetro es por medio de un método `GET`, para lo cual puedes recibir el parámetro de la siguiente forma:

```
lbUsuario.Text = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["nombre"]) ? "" : Request.QueryString["nombre"].ToString();
```

Comment: omg muchas gracias compañero, It works :D

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera de hacerlo seria:

```
if (Request.Params("nombre") != null) 
{
    lbUsuario.Text = Request.Params("nombre");
}
```

Comment: Hola yulfredy, nota que el OP pregunta en lenguaje C#, tu respuesta está indicada en VB. Una opción, es poner tu código de VB con su equivalente de C# para que cuente como una respuesta válida.

Comment: Además, convendría que agregues una descripción, al menos breve, de cómo este código responde a la pregunta.